# Is my google analytics set up correctly for my IOS app?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Following the tutorial on the Google website, I have the following questions.

In my app I add this:

In **appdelegate.m**

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
    // Create tracker instance.
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXX"];
```

then in my main view controller when I want to track some events on the some buttons, I add this code:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAITracker.h" 

   id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];


    if (button.tag==0){
        [tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Preview"
                            withAction:@"Click"
                             withLabel:@"DeckB"
                             withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
    } else if (button.tag==1){
        [tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Preview"
                            withAction:@"Click"
                             withLabel:@"DeckC"
                             withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
    }
```

In my Google analytics account I created the events like this:

1. I went to goals, and then setup new goal.
2. Configured the different fields and set for my events: category matches with Preview action matches with Click label matches with DeckB/DeckC and value left empty

If I run my app I see a message like this:

```
GoogleAnalytics 2.0b4 -[GAIDispatcher cancelTimer] (GAIDispatcher.m:224) DEBUG: Canceled timer with interval 20.0s
```

Does this mean that it is set up correctly? Am I supposed to see that I do have a click on a button after some hours or is there anything else I should do? I just want to see how many times these two button are being pressed.

It would not be a problem with apple review process, right?

Answer (score 2):

If it works, then that message means nothing. If you are deathly concerned about that log message then change this line:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
```

To this:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;
```

However, if it currently does not work, I would check your setup for google analytics. I don't use it so I am not he right person to look at that if it is not working.

It should not interfere with the app review process.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/uqYjTmd4w_E/VzhyxbsD7kQJ

It looks like you need to set up a new property for mobile devices in your Google Analytics account: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2614741?hl=en